# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDDPartition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

I am using Spark2.3.0 and kafka1.0.0.3. I have created a spark read stream

```
df = spark.readStream. \
        format("kafka"). \
        option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost.cluster.com:6667"). \
        option("subscribe", "test_topic"). \
        load(). \
        selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "CAST(timestamp as TIMESTAMP)")
```

It runs succesfully and then

```
df_write = df_read2 \
        .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)",  "CAST(timestamp as TIMESTAMP)") \
        .writeStream \
        .format("csv") \
        .option("path", "/test_streaming_data") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "test_streaming_data/checkpoint") \
        .start()
```

But when I run this

```
df_write.awaitTermination()
```

It throws me an error:

```
    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o264.awaitTermination.
: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Job aborted.
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = c140e21c-f827-4b1d-9182-b3f68a405fad, runId = 47d4b5cb-f223-4235-bef1-84871a2f85c8]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaSource[Subscribe[test_topic]]: {"test_topic":{"0":31300}}}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
Project [cast(key#21 as string) AS key#124, cast(value#22 as string) AS value#125, cast(timestamp#23 as timestamp) AS timestamp#126]
+- Project [cast(key#7 as string) AS key#21, cast(value#8 as string) AS value#22, cast(timestamp#12 as timestamp) AS timestamp#23]
   +- StreamingExecutionRelation KafkaSource[Subscribe[test_topic]], [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:189)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.addBatch(FileStreamSink.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:475)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:472)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1.apply$mcZ$sp(MicroBatchExecution.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:279)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 11, localhost.cluster.com, executor 2): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceRDDPartition
```

Can anyone please help me sorting out the issue?

I have tried replacing the jar libraries with updated ones, but yet the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> tried replacing the jar libraries with updated ones

Unclear what you are doing with this, but you should never modify any JAR files directly.

Use `--packages` option when you run the app. I.e. for latest Spark `2.3.x`, you need this package

```
spark-submit --master=local \
  --packages='org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.4' \
  app.py
```

I have a Jupyter example here - https://github.com/OneCricketeer/docker-stacks/blob/master/hadoop-spark/spark-notebooks/kafka-sql.ipynb